linkToken Issue with react_native/TinyQuickstartReactNative
After setting up the TinyQuickstartReactNative with the information in the readme.md, it seems to have some issues. The server seems to be working correctly since I am getting success requests in the plaid developer log
.
The issue seems to be in the createLinkToken function, it seems like it is not properly setting the link token value after the function is run. With the linkToken not being properly set, it breaks the tokenConfig, which breaks the code that comes after. I tried multiple different ways to change how the linkToken constant data was saved but couldn't find a solution. I was wondering if anyone has run into this issue before or could help me resolve this issue.
Here is where most of the code is (HomeScreen.tsx):

import { link } from 'fs';
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import { Platform, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {PlaidLink, LinkExit, LinkSuccess } from 'react-native-plaid-link-sdk';
var styles = require('./style');
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }: any) => {
const [linkToken, setLinkToken] = useState(null);
const address = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'localhost' : '10.0.2.2';
const createLinkToken = useCallback(async () => {
await fetch(http://${address}:8080/api/create_link_token, {
method: "POST",
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
},
body: JSON.stringify({ address: address })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
setLinkToken(data.link_token);
})
.catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
});
[setLinkToken])
useEffect(() => {
if (linkToken == null) {
createLinkToken();
}
[linkToken]);
return (
<View style={{flex: 1}}>

Tiny Quickstart – React Native


<PlaidLink
tokenConfig={{
token: linkToken,
noLoadingState: false,
}}
onSuccess={async (success: LinkSuccess) => {
await fetch(http://${address}:8080/api/exchange_public_token, {
method: "POST",
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
},
body: JSON.stringify({ public_token: success.publicToken }),
})
.catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
});
navigation.navigate('Success', success);
}}
onExit={(response: LinkExit) => {
console.log(response);
}}>

Open Link




);
};
export default HomeScreen;

For access to all of the code, it is located at the plaid tiny quickstart GitHub:
https://github.com/plaid/tiny-quickstart
I've tried changing the linkToken usestate() to null, string, or blank which did not fix it.
I also tried to capture the link_token data with JSON.Stringify and set then use that as the data for linkToken.

Is this happening with iOS, Android, or both?

It is happening on Andriod. I can only test on Android because I'm on a Windows machine.

As a workaround for now, try downgrading the Plaid Link React Native SDK to 11.5.2

Changing the  Plaid Link React Native SDK to 11.5.2 seemed to fix the issue. I had to resolve many other errors (react-native/android/cmake related) to get the quickstart to work after changing the SDK version, but in the end, I could get it fully working and see the balance response. Thank you so much, Alex!

This was due to a bug in the Tiny Quickstart impacting React Native on Android; the issue has now been fixed.
